# Crear otra consulta con el resultado de otra consulta

Tags: sql, oracle

Quiero usar el valor de la salida (output) de la consulta (en este caso con el alias  *diferencia_de_tiempo*)  y necesito hacer una comparación de valores: el resultado son días y necesito hacer un between entre el 1 al 29 de días. Se va a hacer un update a un campo de la tabla  `= 1`  si es `= 30` o mayor a 30 días; se hará un update a un campo con otro valor `= 3`. No sé si es posible juntos o separados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra _como texto, con formato_ lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y la salida que deseas obtener. Recuerda que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Si que se puede!!! y podes usar tu consulta como from de la que queres usar.. pero aca, no especificaste ningun problema...

Comment: Revisa *subconsulta (subquery)*.